# Is there a way to rename fields in Vega-lite

Tags: vega-lite

In working with data sources that have field names with spaces, I often struggle with having to insert `datum['field name with space']` in various parts of my specs.

I'm looking for a way to (pseudocode) `for(field in fields; replace(field, ' ', '_'))` i.e. replace all of the spaces in field names with underscores.

I used `{"calculate": "datum['Field With Space']", "as": "Field_With_Space"}` which works, but must be done manually for each field, and "worse" leaves the dataset with both the old and new fields.

I note that Vega (but not Vega-lite) has a `project` transform, which might have been able to handle this requirement.

Is there a way to access the collection of field names in the dataset, and potentially "do something" using a string expression with that?

Answer (score 2):

Your current Transform method is the way to go in Vega-lite:

```
"transform": [
{"calculate": "replace(datum['field name with spaces 1'], ' ', '_')", "as": "colA"},
{"calculate": "replace(datum['field name with spaces 2'], ' ', '_')", "as": "colB"},
...
```

However, using javascript you could this without hard-coding any of your columns. Is that an option?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Replace spaces with underscores</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Replace spaces with underscores</h1>
    <p>Open the browser console to view the modified data.</p>
    <script>
      // Load your data into a variable
      const myData = [
        { "field name with spaces 1": 10, "field name with spaces 2": 20 },
        { "field name with spaces 1": 30, "field name with spaces 2": 40 }
      ];

      // Loop over each object in the data array
      const modifiedData = myData.map(obj => {
        // Create a new object to store the modified field names and values
        const newObj = {};

        // Loop over each field in the object
        for (const field in obj) {
          // Replace spaces with underscores in the field name
          const newFieldName = field.replace(/ /g, '_');

          // Add the modified field name and value to the new object
          newObj[newFieldName] = obj[field];
        }

        // Return the modified object
        return newObj;
      });

      // Log the modified data to the console
      console.log(modifiedData);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks - I did come across `replace()` and that does save me from a little bit of typing, but still requires it to be done for each field, and doubles the fields, maybe that's not so bad.  I'm using Deneb in Power BI, so I'm pretty sure I can't do javascript tricks along the way.